# App get crash when i post to Facebook through Graph-API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I'm currently integrating this API 
https://github.com/reallylongaddress...book-Graph-API

The integration all works fine and i'm using the "post" method to post things to peoples walls, all works fine.
The code from the original API does the same, but below is my modified version...

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:6];
[variables setObject:strMessageFb forKey:@"message"];
[variables setObject:@"http://fundaciomiro-bcn.org" forKey:@"link"];
[variables setObject:@"Joan Miró" forKey:@"name"];
[variables setObject:@"I am using Joan Miró's iPhone App, The Ladder of Escape, that allows me to take a tour through the artist's Barcelona. Download it now!" forKey:@"description"];
[variables setObject:@"http://nostrostudio.com/clientes/miro/ICONO_512x512.png" forKey:@"picture"];
[variables setObject:@"L'escala de l'evasió" forKey:@"caption"];

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

But my Problem is,

Its perfectly working on simulator. but when i trying to run on real device i am able to run this script twice. The third time it crashes. I have a feeling it has something to do with the Dictionary.

Any help anyone?

[Also This Post method doesn't working on IOS 5.0 emulator. When i try to post something app get crash but content successfully posted on Facebook.]

Comment: My problem get solved. problem on doGraphPost method return value in FbGraph class file. Now its working fine on both device and simulator.

Comment: Yes, I alos got same problem. Can you please post the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the official SDK, which is [FB iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

You also may post some crash logs...

Comment: i used that sdk also. faced so many problems. thats y travelling through graph api...

Comment: you mentioned that the app crashed. Do you have a crash log?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem get solved. problem on doGraphPost method return value in FbGraph class file. Now its working fine on both device and simulator.